# How to correctly configure docker-compose and nginx for multiple Dash/Flask apps?

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, plotly-dash

I am trying to serve several Dash/Flask apps using docker-compose and nginx. Currently my set-up looks like this:

The Dash app is using host `0.0.0.0` and port `8050`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True, port=8050)
```

In the Dockerfile of the app port `8050` is exposed:

```
FROM python:3.9

# Copy function code
COPY lp_scr_design_app.py /
COPY assets/ assets/
COPY data/ data/

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  ./
RUN pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8050

# Start app
CMD ["python", "lp_scr_design_app.py"]
```

Then nginx is configured such that it passes this app through for the location `/`:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name docker_flask_gunicorn_nginx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://lp_scr_design_app:8050;

        # Do not change this
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        root /static;
    }
}
```

with a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8

RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY project.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Finally in the docker-compose both apps are orchestrated like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  lp_scr_design_app:
    container_name: lp_scr_design_app
    restart: always
    build: ./lp_scr_design_app
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :8050 app:server

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - lp_scr_design_app
```

I can now build and run docker-compose successfully without any issues. However if I try to open the root directory `/` in a browser I get (after a while) a 502 Bad Gateway from nginx.

Where did I go wrong with my set-up here?

Comment: What exactly starting command of your `lp_scr_design_app`. There are two starting command in your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose`. The `command` in your `docker-compose` is overriding the `CMD` in `Dockerfile`. Check your `lp_scr_design_app` is running.

Comment: On the server I want `lp_scr_design_app` to be started by gunicorn. The `CMD` in the Dockerfile is used when I start the app standalone without nginx on my local machine.

Comment: Have you check `lp_scr_design_app` is running?